# Is the maximal ideal of a localization at a prime ideal principal?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X$ be a closed subvariety of $\mathbf P^{n}_{k}$ which is nonsingular in codimension one.
Let $Y$ be a subvariety of $X$ of codimension one, let $\eta$ be its generic point.

First question: is the ideal $m_{\eta}$ of the local ring $O_{X,\eta}$ principal?

Now, let $f$ be a rational function. I'm interested in evaluating $\nu_{Y}(f)$.

Second question (if the answer to the first one is yes): is $\nu_{Y}(f)$ the integer $n$ such that $f=hg^{n}$, where $(g)=m_{\eta}$ and $h$ is invertible in $O_{X,\eta}$?

Thanks!

Comment: 1. Yes. By definition $O_\eta$ is a regular local ring of dim 1, hence a DVR. So $\mathfrak m$ is principal, generated by a uniformiser $g$. 2. Yes, by definition of $\nu_Y$.

Comment: Also: A good place to read about this, in my opinion, is 11.1 of David Eisenbud's book *Commutative Algebra with a View (Toward Algebraic Geometry)*.

Comment: Thank you for your help and suggestions!